# Can a dodecagon be cut into $n$ congruent pieces for any $n$ not of the form $1,2,3,4,6,8,12k^2,24k^2$?

Tags: geometry, tiling, dissection

Suppose I want to cut a regular dodecagon into $n$ congruent simply-connected pieces. For which $n$ is this possible?

I can cut it into 24 right triangles, by cutting from the center to each vertex and the midpoint of each edge; by gluing consecutive such triangles together, I can also get any factor of $24$.

If I cut into either 12 or 24 triangular sectors, I can subdivide each of those triangles into $k^2$ congruent pieces for any positive integer $k$, giving $n=12k^2$ or $n=24k^2$.

Can anything else be done? Obviously if the answer is "no" this is likely to be near-impossible to prove, but I would accept any evidence of someone investigating this problem in the literature and failing to exhibit additional possibilities. (I'd also be interested in partial impossibility proofs - for instance, the case of triangular tiles seems likely to be tractable using the sorts of methodologies Michael Beeson has applied to the problem of tiling a larger triangle.)

I ask about a dodecagon in particular because I recently found a nontrivial tiling of it, shown below:

[image]

but this tiling uses $48$ pieces and so doesn't add anything new to the possible values of $n$.

Edit: This dissection appears in C. Dudley Langford's [*Tiling Patterns for Regular Polygons*](https://doi.org/10.2307/3612553), from 1960.

Comment: @WillJagy Yes? The negation is supposed to be there, I'm interested in values of $n$ besides the ones listed. Is there a mistake in the title I'm missing?

Comment: If you sum up all the internal angles of the pieces, you can probably identify its residue class modulo 2π.

Comment: @WillJagy: Those are indeed the third and fourth sentences of the post. I suppose I could put them even earlier, but I do feel like the post gets to the point pretty quickly?

Comment: @DanAsimov: Not sure I follow; can you say more? I don't see how this could give useful information about the number of tiles, especially with the possibility of non-edge-to-edge tilings.

Comment: I did not consider the possibility of non-edge-to-edge tilings.

Answer (score 3):

**I.** In the figure below, $AOB$, $BOC$ are two adjacent isosceles triangles of the twelve that can tile the dodecagon. Join $AC$, and on $AO$, $CO$ construct isosceles triangles $AEO$, $CDO$ with base angle $=\angle BAC=15^o$, and join $AD$.
[image: triangle/quadrilateral transform]
This produces two quadrilaterals$$AEOD\cong ABCD$$with angles of $45^o$, $150^o$, $60^o$, $105^o$.

Since in area the two quadrilaterals together exceed $\triangle OAB+\triangle OBC$ by $\triangle AEO$, and fall short by $\triangle CDO\cong \triangle AEO$, then$$AEOD=AOB=ABCD=BOC$$and the dodecagon can be tiled with twelve of these congruent quadrilaterals, just as it can be tiled by the twelve congruent isosceles triangles based on the sides of the dodecagon with common vertex at the center.

This transformation of $n$ congruent isosceles triangles into $n$ congruent quadrilaterals which can tile a regular n-gon is evidently possible only for the dodecagon. For congruent triangles $AEO$, $CDO$ must also be congruent with similar triangle $ABC$, but $AC=AO$ only for the dodecagon, since only the regular hexagon has its side equal to the radius of the circumcircle.

**II.** As OP illustrates, the dodecagon can also be tiled by $48$ tiles similar to the above but of one-fourth the area. In the figure below, taking midpoints $Q,F,M,J$ of quadrilateral $ABCD$ and constructing the four congruent quadrilaterals $BQGF$, $JQGH$, $MKGF$, $HGKL$, evidently $ABCD$ exceeds the four quadrilaterals by $\triangle JAQ+\triangle MFC$, but falls short by figure $JHLKMD$.

[image: from 12 to 48]
But joining $HK$ and $DG$, evidently $\triangle LHK\cong \triangle MFC$, and since it can be shown that $\triangle JNH\cong \triangle GPD$ and $\triangle MKP\cong\triangle GDN$, then remaining area $JHKMD=\triangle KHG\cong \triangle AQJ$. Thus we go from a 12-tiling to a 48-tiling. And dividing $AB$, $BC$ into $3$, $4$, or other number of equal parts will yield a tiling by $108$, $192$, and generally $12k^2$ congruent quadrilaterals, which are thus among those already noted by OP.

**III.** If a dodecagon is the only regular polygon that can be non-trivially tiled by congruent quadrilaterals, then it seems the answer is “No, nothing else can be done.”

**Addendum:** In response to OP's comment: Part II. of my answer above might be improved by carrying the construction in the second figure all the way to the center, so as to better compare it with the first figure.

Further, it may help to note what may be obvious, that the quadrilateral in question is the fusion of an equilateral triangle with the side of a triangular half-square.  It is well known that the equilateral triangle, square, and regular hexagon can tile the plane. Further however, squares and equilateral triangles in combination can tile the regular dodecagon. The triangles are double the squares in number, so pairing two triangles with each square yields quadrilaterals equal in number to their component triangles, as seen in the next figure.

[image: square/triangle fusion]

At the risk of confusing the eye, part II. above may be more persuasive if we keep the square/triangle fusion and carry the construction up to the center $O$, i.e. for a full one-sixth of the dodecagon, as in the figure below.
[image: construction carried to center]
Superimpose on the two congruent quadrilaterals and equal isosceles triangles of my first figure the eight congruent quadrilaterals $BQGF$, $JQGH$, $MKGF$, $HGKL$, $LHSO$, $TSHJ$, $JQRT$, $AQRV$. Together they exceed the two isosceles triangles $AOB+BOC$ by triangles $TSO+ART+RAV$, but fall short of them by the respectively equal triangles $KLO+CMK+MCF$.

Since these eight tile one-sixth of the dodecagon, then forty-eight tile the whole.

Comment: I'm not sure how you obtain the $12k^2$ construction in general from the reasoning in part II; what tells you the tiles will necessarily fit together with the right incidence structures? And I don't follow III at all - what counts as a nontrivial tiling, or why a nonexistence proof for other regular polygons would imply the statement (why not pentagonal pieces? why not triangular dissections? why not a different sort of quadrilateral?).

Comment: Addendum tries to improve the argument of part II. Do you agree with the argument of part I (which I was delighted/relieved to discover) that the dodecagon is the only n-gon (besides the hexagon) that can be tiled with congruent quadrilaterals not all having the n-gon center for a vertex? In saying “nontrivial” I meant to be in line with what I took you to be suggesting, that the possible $n$ you note arise from obvious enough tilings—except the “nontrivial” one of your figure.  If $3|n$, $\frac{2n}{3}$ congruent quadrilaterals tile an n-gon, all with a vertex at the center—“trivial” perhaps.

Comment: I agree that the particular construction and incidence structures you exhibit in part I can only work for the dodecagon, but this is very different from proving *every* quadrilateral tiling impossible! There are lots of other ways to tile a regular polygon by quadrilaterals. And in fact it is possible for the regular $3$-gon and $4$-gon at least to be tiled by congruent quadrilaterals in many different ways.

Comment: Yes, I agree there are many ways to tile a regular polygon with congruent quadrilaterals, but please point out any others you know of that are as interesting, i.e. nontrivial, as the one you adduce for the dodecagon.  What are you thinking of regarding the 3-gon and 4-gon? I would agree that possible $n$ for the square are unlimited, since it can be divided into any number of congruent rectangles, but is not $n$ for the congruent quadrilaterals that can tile the equilateral triangle well determined?

Comment: An equilateral triangle can be divided into three congruent quadrilaterals by cutting in "spokes" out from the center; if we do this dissection to each of nine smaller equilateral triangles of a third the side length, some of the resulting quadrilaterals will not touch the border of the triangle. I'm not claiming that I personally know of every possible quadrilateral dissection, though - the whole point is that I'm unsure, so you need to *prove* your claims here in order to provide a satisfying response. As it stands I don't see much justification for the statements in your answer.

Comment: As you say, the equilateral triangle can be tiled with $27=3k^2$ congruent quadrilaterals, only six of which share the center as vertex. So my claim about “nontrivial” quadrilateral tiling being unique to the dodecagon is false. Even if we confine ourselves to the dodecagon, like you now I’m unsure. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: that's great answwr     +1